# Property 'email' does not exist on type 'LoginInfoComponent'. when i am using ng build --prod --build-optimizer

Tags: angular5, typescript2.0

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputsm">User Email</label>
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text[(ngModel)]=email> </div> <br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputsm">Password</label>
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm1" type="text" [(ngModel)]="password"> </div><br>
enter code here<button (click)="subMit(email,password)">Submit</button>
```

TS fie Or Componets

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
 @Component({
selector: 'app-login-info',
templateUrl: './login-info.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login-info.component.css']})
export class LoginInfoComponent implements OnInit {

 public data:any

constructor( private http:HttpClient,private router:Router{}ngOnInit() { }
 subMit(email,password)                                                            { 
this.data=[{  username:email,
  password:password
 }]
if(email=="anand" && password=="anand@123")
{
this.router.navigate(['/dash']);
 localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.data)); }
 else{alert("plz enter UserName or Password Incurrect")} }
public succes(res){}
 public error(res){}}
```

In my command i am using ng build --prod --build-optimizer but it is showing
error like  Property 'email' does not exist on type 'LoginInfoComponent'.

Comment: Can you post the `ts` of your `LoginInfoComponent`?

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { strictEqual } from 'assert';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-info',
  templateUrl: './login-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-info.component.css']
})

Comment: export class LoginInfoComponent implements OnInit {
   public data:any
  constructor( private http:HttpClient,private router:Router) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  subMit(email,password)
  {
     this.data=[{
       username:email,
      password:password
     }]
    debugger;
    if(email=="anand" && password=="anand@123")
    {
      this.router.navigate(['/dash']);
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.data));
    }
    else{alert("plz enter UserName or Password Incurrect")}
  }
public succes(res)
{}
public error(res)
{}}

Comment: Don't put it in the comments, edit the answer and put it there so it's easier to read

Comment: please check now

Comment: Well, the error message is saying that your component doesn't have an `email` property, so when you try to do `[(ngModel)]=email` it fails. Also, your HTML is invalid, you are missing a few `"`

Comment: can you provide any simple example

Comment: thanks lot i got the answer

Comment: You should determine  a scalar variable email in component like this: `public email: string;` before constructor